# Program hangs on Estimator.evaluate in Tensorflow 1.6

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

As a learning tool, I am trying to do something simple.

I have two training CSV files:

One file with 36 columns (3500 records) with 0s and 1s. I am envisioning this file as a flattened 6x6 matrix.
I have another CSV file with 1 columnn of ground truth 0 or 1 (3500 records) which indicates if at least 4 of the 6 of elements in the 6x6 matrix's diagonal are 1's.

I also have two test CSV files which are the same structure as the training files except there are 500 records in each.

When I step through the program using the debugger, it appears that the...

```
estimator.train(
    input_fn=lambda: get_inputs(x_paths=[x_train_file], y_paths=[y_train_file], batch_size=32), steps=100)
```

... runs OK.  I see files in the checkpoint directory and see a loss function graph in Tensorboard.

But when the program gets to...

```
eval_result = estimator.evaluate(
    input_fn=lambda: get_inputs(x_paths=[x_test_file], y_paths=[y_test_file], batch_size=32))
```

... it just hangs.

I have checked the test files and I also tried running the estimator.evaluate using the training files.  Still hangs

I am using TensorFlow 1.6, Python 3.6

The following is all of the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np

x_train_file = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', '6x6_train.csv')
y_train_file  = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', 'HasDiag_train.csv')
x_test_file = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', '6x6_test.csv')
y_test_file  = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', 'HasDiag_test.csv')
model_chkpt = os.path.join('D:', 'Diag', "checkpoints")

def get_inputs(
        count=None, shuffle=True, buffer_size=1000, batch_size=32,
        num_parallel_calls=8, x_paths=[x_train_file], y_paths=[y_train_file]):
    """
    Get x, y inputs.

    Args:
        count: number of epochs. None indicates infinite epochs.
        shuffle: whether or not to shuffle the dataset
        buffer_size: used in shuffle
        batch_size: size of batch. See outputs below
        num_parallel_calls: used in map. Note if > 1, intra-batch ordering
            will be shuffled
        x_paths: list of paths to x-value files.
        y_paths: list of paths to y-value files.

    Returns:
        x: (batch_size, 6, 6) tensor
        y: (batch_size, 2) tensor of 1-hot labels
    """

    def x_map(line):
        n_dims = 6
        columns = [str(i1) for i1 in range(n_dims**2)]
        # Decode the line into its fields
        fields = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[[0]] * (n_dims ** 2))

        # Pack the result into a dictionary
        features = dict(zip(columns, fields))
        return features

    def y_map(line):
        y_row = tf.string_to_number(line, out_type=tf.int32)
        return y_row

    def xy_map(x, y):
        return x_map(x), y_map(y)

    x_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(x_train_file)
    y_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(y_train_file)

    combined = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_ds, y_ds))
    combined = combined.repeat(count=count)
    if shuffle:
        combined = combined.shuffle(buffer_size)
    combined = combined.map(xy_map, num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
    combined = combined.batch(batch_size)
    x, y = combined.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return x, y

columns = [str(i1) for i1 in range(6 ** 2)]

feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(name)
    for name in columns]

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                   hidden_units=[18, 9],
                                   activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                   n_classes=2,
                                   model_dir=model_chkpt)

estimator.train(
    input_fn=lambda: get_inputs(x_paths=[x_train_file], y_paths=[y_train_file], batch_size=32), steps=100)

eval_result = estimator.evaluate(
    input_fn=lambda: get_inputs(x_paths=[x_test_file], y_paths=[y_test_file], batch_size=32))

print('\nTest set accuracy: {accuracy:0.3f}\n'.format(**eval_result))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parameters that are causing this:

- [`tf.data.Dataset.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) has a `count` parameter:

  > `count`: (Optional.) A `tf.int64` scalar `tf.Tensor`, representing the
  >   number of times the dataset should be repeated. The default behavior
  >   (if `count` is `None` or `-1`) is for the dataset be repeated indefinitely.

  In your case, `count` is always `None`, so the dataset is repeated indefinitely.
- [`tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#evaluate) has the `steps` parameter:

  > `steps`: Number of steps for which to evaluate model. If `None`, evaluates until `input_fn` raises an end-of-input exception.

  Steps are set for the training, but not for the evaluation, as a result the estimator is running until `input_fn` raises an end-of-input exception, which, as described above, never happens.

You should set either of those, I think `count=1` is the most reasonable for evaluation.

Comment: I fixed my run by adding a `steps` value (set to 1). This seems like bad design when the input function returns ndarray values, in which case there is an obvious stopping point that is apparently ignored (without a `steps` value).